# Xcode 5.1.1 - ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5

On Xcode 5.1.1 even after adding folder I get the following error:

```
" ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found".
```

Comment: check if the file is there index.html

Comment: @PrathameshSaraf i checked. And it is "index.html" not "Index.html"

Comment: Can you open the index.html in a browser?

Comment: What is the URL for it?

Comment: @smj2393 www/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you put the index in the right folder? It should be something like: `*packagename*\platforms\ios\www\index.html`

Comment: @smj2393 index is in "projectname/www/".  i generate project in xcode 4, not in CLI

Comment: Hmmm, it might be worth starting again and downloading XCode 5, installing the latest version of Cordova 3.4.0 and following the command line method: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html
Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other problems.

Comment: check in config.xml what is the src value for key <content>. It should be something like <content src="index.html" />

Answer (score 1):

i have faced a similar problem - i'm on xcode 5.1.1 (android runs fine) - i did:

```
$ cordova -v
3.4.1-0.1.0

$ cordova run ios
<ios simulator : ERROR: Start Page at 'www/index.html' was not found.>

$ cordova serve ios
Static file server running on port 8001 (i.e. http://localhost:8001)
<in a browser i can do http://localhost:8001/ios/www/index.html>
```

index.html file is there:

```
$ tree -L 1 platforms/ios/www/
platforms/ios/www/
├── README.md
├── cordova.js
├── cordova_plugins.js
├── css
├── img
├── index.html
├── js
├── lib
├── plugins
└── templates
```

well its no an answer sorry but an elaboration :)

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml make sure you have the `content` setup properly to point to the `index.html` file like this:
[image]